# Recognize bash variable as distinct word

Tags: cursor-motions

Is there any way to make vim treat bash variables (anything prefixed with a `$`, really) as distinct words? For instance, with the following lines:

```
"name $suffix.ext"
"name$suffix.ext"
```

with the cursor somewhere in `$suffix`, the motion <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> should leave me with `"name .ext"` and `"name.ext"`, respectively.

My primary reason for wanting this is to enable me to use some mappings I have for wrapping words in quotes/parens/etc with bash variables. I'm okay with changing the mapping as long as it still works with normal words, but I would prefer not to have to make this a syntax-specific mapping (but if there's no easy way around that, I can deal with it). (Here's one of the quote wrapping mappings I referenced: `nnoremap <leader>" viw<esc>a"<esc>hbi"<esc>lel`)

Initially, I thought I could do this with `set iskeyword`, but I could only make that work for cases such as `name $suffix.ext`, and it then makes performance for `name$suffix.ext` cases worse, in my opinion.

My other thoughts were along the lines of getting vim to recognize `$` and `[any word separator]` as either

- a matching pair (like `{` and `}`( this seems like too much potential for bad side effects))
- or a "tag" (i.e., like html/xml tags that <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>) recognizes (never messed with those, so I wasn't sure where to begin there)

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18202/modify-iskeyword-for-keyword-local-completion-only. Not a duplicate, though solved with a (hand-written) text object as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be a case deserving a new text object. With Kana's framework (`vim-textobj-user`) in place, it would be something like this:

```
" define av/iv to select a bash variable:
call textobj#user#plugin('bash', {
        \  'avar': {
        \   'pattern': '\$\w\+\>',
        \   'select': [ 'av'],
        \  },
        \  'ivar': {
        \   'pattern': '\$\zs\w\+\>',
        \   'select': [ 'iv'],
        \  },
        \  'var': {
        \   'pattern': ['\${', '}'],
        \   'select-i': [ 'iV'],
        \   'select-a': [ 'aV'],
        \  },
        \ })
```

... and then I can use 'div', 'yav' etc. to delete inside the object (skipping the `$`) or yank the whole variable, and use `iV`/`aV` for the `${var}` format.

I hope a more enterprising soul can unify those formats, to use a single code letter (e.g. `v`) in both cases.

However, this won't work with the mapping you mentioned for a few reasons. First, the mapping would need to be recursive to take advantage of the new text object. Second, the map would need to use different movements to reach the start/end of the word. Staying approximately similar to what you have already, this mapping should work:

```
nmap <leader>" vav<esc>`>a"<esc>`<i"<esc>f"
```

This uses the selection based movements `` `> `` and `` `< `` to reach the end and beginning of the selection, respectively. However, this might not play well with other mappings/plugins/etc that you may have, so be wary of that. Furthermore, this will not allow the mapping to work for normal words. To do that you would have to modify the text object to overwrite the default `w` behavior.

Comment: This was definitely better than what I had, but while it didn't give me exactly what I wanted (due to not working with my mappings for quote-wrapping), it didn't require much tweaking to make it do what I needed. I changed `'pattern': '\$\w\+\>'` to `'pattern': '\$\?\w\+\>'`, `'select': [ 'av']` to `'select': [ 'aw']`, and altered my mapping from `viw<esc>a"<esc>hbi"<esc>lel` to ``vaw<esc>`>a"<esc>"<i`<esc>f"``. Accepting since it did answer the root question, even if it didn't quite work for my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `$` to the `iskeyword` option for shell scripts in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
augroup shellscript
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType sh setlocal iskeyword+=$
augroup END
```

Alternatively, you could do that in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim`:

```
setlocal iskeyword+=$
```

Comment: OP mentions that he's already tried this in his question. If you're posting this because it's definitely the only possible solution, you should probably say so explicitly.