# Modify `iskeyword` for keyword-local completion only

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions, map-operator, filetype-sh

#### Context

Some time ago, I added the following line to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim` to make working with parameter expansions easier:

```
setlocal iskeyword+=$
```

This is nice to be able to e.g. `ysiw"` via surroud.vim to surround a parameter expansion in quotes.

#### Problem

However, I've noticed that when doing keyword-local completion (`i_<C-n>`), typing `$partial_var_name` will not complete to `full_var_name` unless `$full_var_name` is also present in the file already. This I sort of expect.

I would like to fix it.

#### Attempted Solution

I tried the following (there is no `CompleteStart` event, unfortunately):

```
 " Fix keywords
 setlocal iskeyword+=$

augroup sh_ftplugin
  au!
  au MenuPopup setlocal iskeyword-=$
  au CompleteDone setlocal iskeyword+=$
augroup END
```

It did not work.

## TL;DR

My question is thus, how can I make insert-mode completion work the way I would like?

**My thoughts**

- by ignoring `iskeyword` in completion,
- modifying it during completion
- defining a text object for parameter expansions—neat plugin idea, by the way
- changing how I use `iskeyword` as a last resort (that is, removing `$` permanently)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote my own solution by creating a parameter-expansion text object, something I'd been meaning to do for a while anyway.

I include the full code at the very end, which I place in `~/.vim/autoload/sh.vim`.

Then, in my `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim`, I remove the `setlocal iskeyword+=$` line. **This is the key step**, since it allows completion to work again.

I add

```
xnoremap <buffer> <silent> iv :<C-u>call sh#in_parameter_expansion()<CR>
onoremap <buffer> <silent> iv :<C-u>call sh#in_parameter_expansion()<CR>
```

This allows me to do things like `viv` and `div` to modify parameter expansions. `iv` stands for "in variable" (`ip` and `ap` are taken for paragraphs)—one can easily use whatever mappings they wish.

---

**Bonus**

I also created the following mapping to make use of `surround.vim` as mentioned in the question:

```
" Relies on surround.vim and custom text object above
nmap <buffer> <silent> <LocalLeader>qv ysiv"
```

We need `nmap` here because we *want* recursive mapping expansion. But now a simple `<LocalLeader>qv` (read: quote variable) will quote a parameter expansion (this is a common refactor for me).

In the most up-to-date version, I include a text-object for subshells (`$(...)`). It handles nested expansions and arithmetic as well. See the link under **Code**.

---

**Code**

Well commented, with some patterns generalized.

You can find the most up-to-date version [in my dotfiles on github](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/autoload/bk/sh.vim).

```
" ~/.vim/autoload/sh.vim
" Based on https://vimways.org/2018/transactions-pending/

" Text object for shell parameter expansions
" Definitions:
"   Parameter: An entity that stores values. It can be a name, a number, or one
"   of the special characters listed below. A variable is a parameter denoted by
"   a name.
"   Name: A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and
"   beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and
"   function names. Also referred to as an identifier.
"   Positional Parameters: Any parameter denoted by one or more digits. Those
"   with multiple digits require braces.
"   Special Parameters: The following list:
"     - *
"     - @
"     - #
"     - ?
"     - -
"     - $
"     - !
"     - 0
"     - _
"  Expansion: Any usage of a parameter's value in place of its name: the common
"  forms include $var and ${var}. The more 'esoteric' options are documented
"  under 'Parameter Expansion' in bash(1).
"
"  In general, one wants to select the entire expansion construct in order to
"  e.g. surround in quotes (a common idiom). This means:
"    - $
"    - a parameter (name or special); or,
"    - a brace construction:
"      - {
"      - !, optionally                               -+
"      - parameter (name or special)                  |-basically 'anything'
"      - an expansion option (see above), optionally -+
"      - }
"
"  In the case of the braces, we can simply select the ${...}. Sans braces, we
"  have to match exactly the definition of a parameter. We construct a regex for
"  this purpose.

function! s:branchify_atoms(atoms)
  return join(a:atoms, '\|')
endfunction

function! s:group_atoms(atoms)
  return map(copy(a:atoms), 'printf("\\(%s\\)", v:val)')
endfunction

" matches a name (no braces)
let s:name_pattern = '\m' " magic mode
let s:name_pattern .= '\(\a\|_\)' " begins with alpha or underscore
let s:name_pattern .= '\(\a\|\d\|_\)*' " letters, numbers, underscores

" matches a positional parameter (no braces)
let s:positional_pattern = '\m' " magic
let s:positional_pattern .= '[1-9]' " a single digit

" matches any of the special parameters (no braces)
let s:special_pattern = '\m' " magic
let s:special_pattern .= s:branchify_atoms(
      \ [
      \ '\*',
      \ '@',
      \ '#',
      \ '?',
      \ '-',
      \ '\$',
      \ '!',
      \ '0',
      \ '_'
      \ ]
      \ ) " special params as branches

let s:parameter_pattern = '\m' " magic
let s:parameter_pattern .= s:branchify_atoms(
      \ s:group_atoms(
      \   [s:name_pattern, s:positional_pattern, s:special_pattern],
      \   )
      \ )

" matches anything in braces
let s:brace_pattern = '\m' " magic
let s:brace_pattern .= '{' " opening brace
let s:brace_pattern .= '.\{-}' " anything, but non-greedy: there may be two braces in one line
let s:brace_pattern .= '}' " closing brace

" matches a $ followed by a parameter or a brace construction
let s:expansion_pattern = '\m' " magic
let s:expansion_pattern .= '\$' " literal '$'
let s:expansion_pattern .= s:group_atoms(
      \ [s:branchify_atoms(
      \   s:group_atoms(
      \     [s:parameter_pattern, s:brace_pattern],
      \     )
      \   )]
      \ )[0] " extract the one and only element

function! sh#in_parameter_expansion() abort
  let l:line = line('.')
  if !search(s:expansion_pattern, 'ce', l:line)
    return
  endif
  normal! v
  call search(s:expansion_pattern, 'cb', l:line)
endfunction
```